# I want to filter by id

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I want to filter my array of song by title and id but typescript throwing me error that property tolowercase() does not exit on type number

```
public querySongs() {
    let    song: Song[] = [];
    song =  this.song.filter((item) => {
        return item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.queryText.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
        item.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.queryText.toLowerCase()) > -1
    });
    this.song = song;
}
```

filtering by title works fine but by id keeps given me this error

"Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'number'"

Comment: Is `item.id` supposed to be a string? If so, the value you're getting isn't what you think it is, and the problem is probably in whatever code populates `this.song`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is clear enough, the item is dynamically cast as number type. Try to cast it to string by appending .toString()

Instead of

```
return item.title.toLowerCase()...
```

Change it like this

```
return item.title.toString().toLowerCase()
```

or you can use ternary to identify whether it's string type or not

```
return typeof item.title === 'string' ? item.title.toLowerCase() : item.title
```

Answer (score 1):

So if error says that the toLowerCase not exist on type number this means that type number can't be "toLowerCase" cuz the number is not a string. Change type to string if your id contains any letters.

Answer (score 1):

If the id's are stored as numbers then .toLowerCase() won't work because that only works on string's you need to stringify the id's

```
 public querySongs() {
    let    song: Song[] = [];
       song =  this.song.filter((item) => { return item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.queryText.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
            item.id.stringify().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.queryText.toLowerCase()) > -1
    });
        this.song = song;
}
```